# AngularJs ng change only when values change in Text Box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text box in my Application, i am using change-on-blur custom directive to validate that field on tab out that is, if i type ABCD initially in that text box then i delete D character and again i type D character so custom change-on-blur will call only one time.

For some issues i am using `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-change="validate(data)"` instead ng-blur for that element. So if i type ABCD it will call the function, again i delete and type D character it will call that function again. Is there custom ng-change directive to call only once.

I am struggling with this for last 2 days. Kindly help

Html :

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="data.taxNo" id="taxNo" 
        ngomitsplchar class="form-control taxNo" 
        maxlength="15" style="text-transform: uppercase;" 
        ng-paste="$event.preventDefault();"
        ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" 
        ng-change="validate(data)" 
        tabindex="5" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="nope">
```

JS:

```
$scope.validate = function (obj) {
        alert("2"); // Prompting alert 2 times when using ng-change
    // Prompting alert 1 times when using change-on-blur

}

app.directive('changeOnBlur', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (attrs.type === 'radio' || attrs.type === 'checkbox') 
                return;

            var expressionToCall = attrs.changeOnBlur;

            var oldValue = null;
            elm.bind('focus',function() {
                //scope.$apply(function() {
                    oldValue = elm.val();
                //});
            });
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    var newValue = elm.val();
                    if (newValue !== oldValue){
                        scope.$eval(expressionToCall);
                    }
                        //alert('changed ' + oldValue);
                });         
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you make it more clear?

Comment: @Wolverine I am using ng-change with ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" for Text Box, i need to restrict duplicate call when values change in text box, that is if i type N number of times ABCD should call only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Need to change  from  `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`  to `ng-model-options="{updateOn: '**change blur**'}"`. So its restricted duplicate call when changing same value in text box by using `ng-change="validate(data)"`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.taxNo" id="taxNo" 
        ngomitsplchar class="form-control taxNo" 
        maxlength="15" style="text-transform: uppercase;" 
        ng-paste="$event.preventDefault();"
        ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change blur'}" 
        ng-change="validate(data)" 
        tabindex="5" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="nope">
```